# Windows Xp Home Network Pc's don't show up on My network places

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I have set up a Windows home network and called it RHOME now the problem is that i can find some pc's on the network. This network has been set up for file sharing hence i need to find the files. Are there any other softwares that will help me detect all the pc's on the network all the pc's are on the 192.168.1 range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution I had for additional security disabled options on the lan adapter i.e. file and printer sharing and client for microsoft networks were unchecked. And hence some pc's which had these unchecked were non-discoverable on the local network

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the workgroup name matches on all of the systems and make sure that you have actually shared out a directory.  Xp Home, from my experience, doesn't show up on the network until it is actually sharing out files or directories.

Comment: I haven't shared a directory on any of the computers, yet some show up and some don't. I'll try what you have mentioned here though. Also by default doesn't it share my documents or some shared folders?

Comment: tried that and it didn't work, wonder what I have done wrong here.. hmmm..